# Let $M$ be a finite model of a language where nonlogical symbols are only constants and symbols of $1-$aria relation.

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, automorphism-group

Let Aut$ (M)$ be the automorphism group ($M$ isomorphisms in and of itself). Show That there are natural numbers $n_1,. . . , n_k$ such that the number of elements of Aut $(M)$ is $n_1! · · · n_k!$.

The ideal solution to this problem is to understand it too well, but I fail to grasp the essence of what they ask to try, could someone explain to me the way forward and give me an explanation of what this result means, please?

Comment: Why not start with an example? Suppose there's just one unary relation $P$, and $M$ has $7$ elements: $3$ elements satisfying $P$ and $4$ elements not satisfying $P$. What does an automorphism of $M$ look like?